# Setting Serilog log file location at run time in C#

Tags: c#, .net, logging, dependency-injection, serilog

I am writing a small console application , and using Serilog for logging.
I have a logging service registered as shown

```
logFilelocation = "C:/Applications"
services.AddSingleton<IMyLogger>(x => new MyLogger(new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(logFileLocation, rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Month).CreateLogger()));
```

where logFileLocation is a default value;

When the program starts, it does:

```
  IMyLogger _logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IMyLogger>();
```

But I want to update the logFileLocation  when user gives input at run time.
How can I set this logFileLocation at run time in this case???

Comment: https://nblumhardt.com/2023/02/dynamically-reload-any-serilog-sink/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @ThomasArdal; I could do a Hot-reload by modifying

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyLogger>(x => new MyLogger(new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Map(
                 _ => GetLogFileLocation(),
                    (url, wt) => wt.File($@"{url}\Log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month),
        sinkMapCountLimit: 1)
    .CreateLogger()));
```

Where GetLogFileLocation() returns a property that represents the path.